# Google Zoom Button Shows Broken Image

Tags: android, api, dictionary

I am using Google Map APIs in my Android app with Visual Studio. When debugging my app in visual studio, using Windows, all works fine.

When I install my app on my Android phone, the Map load correctly, but the Google Logo, Zoom In and Zoom Out image is broken.  They still function as normal and do zoom in and out fine.

Why is the image broken?
[Image From App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCoVd.jpg)